# jQuery Plugin Authoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Any idea why this basic example doesn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq6pz/

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.testPlugin = function( options ) {  
        alert('hi');
  };
})( jQuery );

$.testPlugin();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you added your plugin to the `fn` namespace not to the `$` namespace. So `$().testPlugin()` will work but `$.testPlugin()` does not.

If you want to pollute the `$` namespace you can do:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.testPlugin = function( options ) {  
        alert('hi');
  };
})( jQuery );

$.testPlugin();
```

My rule of thumb I follow is: use `$.` when it is not DOM related (like ajax), and use `$.fn.` when it operates on elements grabbed with a selector (like DOM/XML elements).

Comment: @Chad, well said +1. Also I'm a sucker for Aladdin.

Comment: @Chad +1.  Excellent, clean explanation

Comment: Is it best practice to use the `$` namespace if my plugin doesn't operate on a DOM but on an object? Lets say... `num = 5;` And my plugin does like a square. So `$.square(num)`

Comment: @jon In that case I would do `$.square` because a jQuery wrapped `Number` isn't very useful...But if it is something like an object `{}` or array `[]` then I may use `$.fn.` since many jQuery functions are useful for these types and I may wrap it under the hood anyway. Very much so depends.

Comment: @Chad thanks. What if I do have an object, and the function is more complex. Say... `data = {numbers: [1,2,3,4,5], otherstuff: []}` and I want to do chaining like this `$(data).process().filterPrimeNumbers().sortBy('desc');`? Or even... `x = $(data).process(); x.sortBy('asc');`

Comment: @jon Like I said, it depends. Usually if I am operating on an object or array then I wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a selector:

```
$(document).testPlugin();
$(window).testPlugin();
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Kq6pz/1/