# jQuery Plugin - How to add / bind events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Ok this is my first stab at creating a jQuery plugin so I am going off tutorials currently.

This far I have

```
(function($)
{
    $.tippedOff = function(selector, settings)
    {
        var config = {
            'top':0,
            'left':0,
            'wait':3000
        };
        if(settings){$.extend(config, settings);}

        var $elem = $(selector);
        if($elem.length > 0)
        {
            $elem.each(function()
            {
                $(this).css({"color":"#F00"});
            })
        }

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Which works for changing the text color of the provided elements. However. I want to add functionality to elements that the plugin takes effect on. Such as a hover or click event. But I can't wrap my head around that idea at the moment, seeing as the `selector` can be anything. So its not like I can hardcode something in per say thats specific like I would through normal jQuery methods.

So, with that, how do I go about adding that type of functionality to things after its been rendered?

Comment: Do it just like you would outside of a plugin. `$elem.click(handler)`

Comment: so would I add classes or ids or whatever to the elements as I go down the line so I can do something like that? So there is something definitive I can rely on to use as the selector?

Comment: you don't need a selector, you've already selected the element.

Comment: May be a silly question, but are you following this - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring ? Everything you need to get you started is explained pretty well there.

Comment: Ironically no.. I just googled, and skimmed over a couple blogs for examples. Found the one with the most details, sought comparison between the ones to figure out the "standard" of starting on, and am kinda working out the rest on my own as I tend to learn better through trial and error, then trying to copy something exactly and then modifying said copy.. Also didn't think of checking the actual jquery docs for plugin authoring for examples.. only go there for api usage when Im stuck on a particular function

Comment: What do you want the plugin to do, ideally?

Comment: @KevinB you mean as a method param? This "plugin" is inserted right into `$`, not the usual `$.fn` prototype, so it does require a selector. (One might also point out that this pattern is bad/wrong.)

Comment: Ah, I see @Dom already has pointed out the _right_ way to author a plugin.

Comment: @Mathletics Right, but he already has it as a parameter, and has already used said parameter to select the element. I admit, that comment wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When creating plugins, it is very easy to over-complicate things, so try to keep things nice and simple.

I have provided you with ***TWO*** examples of the `tippedOff` plugin. Here is also a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsbin.com/ukotit/39/edit) of both plugins.

The first uses your original code as is (**NO SIGNIFICANT CHANGES MADE**):

```
$.tippedOff = function(selector, settings)
    {
        var config = {
            'top':0,
            'left':0,
            'wait':3000
        };
        if(settings){$.extend(config, settings);}

        var $elem = $(selector);
        if($elem.length > 0)
        {
            $elem.each(function()
            {
              //bind mouseenter, mouseleave, click event
                $(this).css({"color":"#F00"})
                .mouseenter(function(){
                  $(this).css({"color":"green"});
                })
                .mouseleave(function(){
                  $(this).css({"color":"#F00"});
                })
                .click(function(){
                  $(this).html('clicked');
                });

            })
        }

        return this;
    };
```

This one, however, is based on your original code. Basically, I have reconstructed your original code using [these tips](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). This is how I would personally go about it.  I have also provided you with a breakdown below of changes made. (**SIGNIFICANT CHANGES MADE**):

```
$.fn.tippedOff = function(settings) {
      var config = $.extend( {
          'top':0,
          'left':0,
          'wait':3000,
          'color': 'orange',
          'hoverColor': 'blue'
      }, settings);

      return this.each(function() {
          $this = $(this);
          $this.css({ 'color': config.color})
          .mouseenter(function(){
             $this.css({ 'color': config.hoverColor });
          })
          .mouseleave(function(){
             $this.css({ 'color': config.color });
          })
          .click(function(){
             $this.html('clicked');
          });
      });
    }
```

### ----------------------------------------

### Breakdown:

***Original Code:***

```
$.tippedOff = function(selector, settings) {
```

***Changed:***

```
$.fn.tippedOff = function( settings ) {
```

**Comments:**

The difference between `$.tippedOff` and `$.fn.tippedOff` is huge! Adding your plugin to the `$.fn` namespace rather than the `$` namespace will prevent you from having to provide a `selector` and makes life simplier.

I personally like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393661/jquery-plugin-authoring/15393690#answer-15393702), in which @Chad states:

> My rule of thumb I follow is: use $. when it is not DOM related (like ajax), and use $.fn. when it operates on elements grabbed with a selector (like DOM/XML elements).

---

***Original Code:***

```
if(settings){$.extend(config, settings);}
```

***Changed:***

```
var config = $.extend( {
          'top':0,
          'left':0,
          'wait':3000
      }, settings);
```

**Comments:**

Having an `if` statement is redundant. [`.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) does all the work for you.

---

***Original Code:***

```
var $elem = $(selector);
        if($elem.length > 0)
        {
            $elem.each(function()
            {
                $(this).css({"color":"#F00"});
            })
        }

        return this;
```

***Changed:***

```
return this.each(function() {
          $this = $(this);
          $this.css({ 'color': config.color});
});
```

**Comments:**

Using `return this.each(function(){})` is good practice and maintains chainability. Not only that, you will no longer need to worry about the `selector`'s length.

---

*NOTE: If you want to add additional events, then use different `methods` within your plugin: [jQuery Doc Reference - Authoring Plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Events).

I hope this helps and please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 4):

I have not enough reputation points to comment and fully agree with Dom, who is very knowledgeable. I only would like to add that within the changed code it would be better to create a **local** variable by using the **var** keyword:
`var $this = $(this);`
This will make the plugin better and allows you to apply the plugin to multiple elements one the page as for example:
`$('#testX').tippedOff2();`
`$('#testY').tippedOff2();`
`$('#testZ').tippedOff2();`